# JavaScript window not identical nor equal to window in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

normally, if you call a function as a function (not as a method of an object), the ***this*** variable points to the global object (which is the window object in browsers). I have found a situation, where, in IE8, the ***this*** variable is not identical (===), nor equal (==) to the window object:
http://jsfiddle.net/zgJGU/1/

if you take a look at the code, you may notice an even stranger behaviour: the value ***global*** changes, as it is being returned from the function (inside the function it is not equal to window; outside of the function it is equal to the window)

(you may ask, why is this an important issue? because I would like to check if my function was called as a function, or as a method of an object.)

can you give some explanation for this strange behaviour?
(or a correct way to check if a function was called as a method, or as a function)

Comment: In IE8 (emulated in IE9), I'm getting `true true false true`. In IE9 they all give `true`, as does Chrome. I guess it's a bug.

Comment: in **real** IE8 (not emulated in IE9) it's false false false true

Answer (score 1):

That indeed is a very weird issue that you uncovered. If you implicitly created a new function in the global scope then the results are probably what you expect. I've modified your jsFiddle and show part of it below... http://jsfiddle.net/VYcmT/

```
var ff = function() {
    var global = this;
    console.log(global === window);        // true       
    console.log(global == window);         // true
    return global;
};
var global = ff();
console.log(global === window);            // true
console.log(global == window);             // true
```

The weird part is that if you define a function explicitly off the global scope (`window`), as in the following snippet, then IE8 starts to get confused... http://jsfiddle.net/zsWUK/

It seems that when you explicitly assign a function to the `window` and then invoke it that IE8 somehow makes `this` special in some way. Comparing the `window` property off of `this` results in a positive comparison. It looks as if IE8 treats `this` as some kind of wrapper around the `window` object.

```
window.ff = function() {
    var global = this;
    console.log(global === window);        // false       
    console.log(global == window);         // false
    console.log(global.window === window); // true
    console.log(global.window == window);  // true
    return global;
};
var global = ff();
console.log(global === window);            // false
console.log(global == window);             // true
console.log(global === window.window);     // true
console.log(global == window.window);      // true
```

The good news is that both the above and following code snippets all return `true` in Chrome, Firefox, IE9/10, etc...